# Execution failed for task ‘:mergeDebugResources’ ionic 2

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am developing an application with ionic 2 and I am getting the error below after run "ionic build android"

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mergeDebugResources'.
> Error: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: Failed to crunch file C:\TFS\aplicativos\Hibrido\gerador-argumentos-politico\projeto\platforms\androi
d\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.google.android.gms\play-services-base\10.2.1\res\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_backgroun
d.9.png into C:\TFS\aplicativos\Hibrido\gerador-argumentos-politico\projeto\platforms\android\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-xxhdpi-v4\common_go
ogle_signin_btn_icon_light_normal_background.9.png

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

Someone know what I do? I already tried of all solution in forum ionic until now, and all solutions don't worked for me.
Could you please help me with this?
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to the length of the path to your ionic project.So just move your project very close to the hard drive letter as like below.

```
c:\MyIonic2>ionic build android
```

Comment: It's my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

For Future Ref. I had the exact same issue. In my case the resources were broken/damaged. Just removed them and added from backup or use ionic resource gen as mentioned on [Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-execution-failed-for-task-mergedebugresources/90764/3)

Comment: this is the one slution for me

Comment: Great ! the issue for my was with "ionic cordova resources", you have to let the generation finish, i my case resources were broken. thx.

Comment: wao... I came back looking for this solution.